# R Shiny Bar Plot and input$var issue

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

There is some issue with the input variable type that is preventing the R Shiny work. The drop down is generated and I can choose the variable, but no plot is generated and I get no error message. If I substitute by the ggplot with the data frame name and field directly (commented one), the bar graph is generated.
I have tried the as.character (gives me an error), no conversion or as.factor (give no error, but does not generate the bar plot.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
# DEFINE UI FUNCTION #######################################
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Charting GE Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Dropdown menu for selecting variable from GE data.
      selectInput("var2",
                  label = "Select X Axis Variable",
                  choices = c("Indicator_Type" = 12, "Class" = 13),
                  selected = 13)  # Default selection
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("BarPlot")  
    )
  )
)
# DEFINE SERVER FUNCTION ###################################
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Define bar plot output
  output$BarPlot <- renderPlot({  
    iX   <- as.factor(input$var2) #
    xvar    <- Event_identity_noNAsComp[, iX]
    require(graphics)
   g <- ggplot(Event_identity_noNAsComp, aes(xvar, fill = xvar))
  #  g <- ggplot(Event_identity_noNAsComp, aes(Event_identity_noNAsComp$Class, #fill = Event_identity_noNAsComp$Class))
  g + geom_bar()        
  })
}
# CALL THE SHINY APP #######################################
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```
iX   <- as.numeric(input$var2)
```

If it is not necessary to provide the column number position, it will work if you provide the column name:

E.g.

```
  # Dropdown menu for selecting variable from GE data.
  selectInput("var2",
              label = "Select X Axis Variable",
              choices = c("Mkt Returns" = "mktreturns", "Mkt Prices" = "mktprices"),
              selected = "mktreturns")
```

So for me I used a data set below:

```
summary(df_bm)
```

---

```
     Date        mktreturns          mktprices
```

2013-02-14:   1   Min.   :-2095.500   Min.   :1890
 2013-02-15:   1   1st Qu.:  -13.000   1st Qu.:2395
 2013-02-18:   1   Median :    0.000   Median :2665
 2013-02-19:   1   Mean   :   -5.361   Mean   :2597
 2013-02-20:   1   3rd Qu.:    8.000   3rd Qu.:2842
 2013-02-21:   1   Max.   :  268.000   Max.   :3378
 (Other)   :1007

Comment: Thank you; it actually works just with as.numeric; I did not realize that conversion was related to how I define the select input

Comment: Great, I'll edit the answer, yeah it's almost habit for me to do as.numeric with as.character, but is redundant in this case

Comment: It's because selectInput returns a string, so in your code when you pass it in . the data frame searches for a column name of "2" rather than a position of numeric 2, if the answer is helpful just give it an up vote, thanks